# Opencart filter_id or value in product view

Tags: php, mysql, css, opencart

I am creating an open cart shop and I want to display filter value or id at product view

For example I would have a filter called "plastic", "metal" and etc.

Displaying the filter id or value would allow me to style the product via css.

For example product with "metal"  would be a little more grey.

Is there any way to do that on open cart ?

Comment: Technically you can do anything with Opencart but the code itself is a mess to navigate through. It is definitely possible though.

Comment: @MrJack If You find open source and free e-commerce solution written in MVC with same or better features that is *not a mess* (don't even try to mention Magento!) I'll buy you a bottle of scotch! IMHO, OpenCart is written in very clean way and the code is very easy to follow. And I am sure many OpenCart developers will agree with me.

Comment: @Andy, yes, it is possible. But here you are maybe misusing Filters or at least you are exchanging the terms with product attributes, am I right? Filters are used when searching or listing through products so that You can set special criteria while attributes are used for defining different properties of each product.

Comment: @shadyyx What I need here is clearly not attributes, I know what filters are for and I intend to use them for that matter, this is just  a visual addon on the product page. I could use tags for this and add styling on that, but I think using filters makes more sense here.

Comment: @shadyyx I use opencart because all the others suck more. But for a programmer, the code is ugly. It works though, so in the end its all that matters. Also, they are fixing a lot of it for version 2.0 (check it out on github). As for OP, show us some code, we'll tell you what doesn't work. We wont code a module for you. If you want that, try the OpenCart forums, though you'll have to fork some money over.